# Definition and Example of Polytope Shelling.

Tags: polytopes, discrete-geometry

I'm trying to get this definition of polytope shelling right through an example, but I'm afraid I might be misunderstanding it.

[image]

[image]

By the definition and remark above, this "shelling" of a tetrahedron should work.

[image]

But doesn't we run into a problem when $F_2$ is added to the "shelling" after $F_1$? Since the shelling of the boundary complex of $F_2$ is 1-dimensional, but $F_2 \cap F_1$ is a point, I don't see how that would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$F_2 \cap F_1$ isn't a point, it's an edge.

Then $F_3 \cap (F_1 \cup F_2)$ consists of two edges, and $F_4 \cap (F_1 \cup F_2 \cup F_3)$ consists of three edges.

Comment: How do I know that just by looking at the polytopal complexes? I think I'm not reading it right.

Comment: It's a tetrahedron. The intersection of any two facets is an edge. In general, in any $d$-simplex, the intersection of any two facets is a $(d-2)$-face. You can't see that in your picture in the post; if you draw it that way you have to remember that you've drawn several edges twice. You can use a Schlegel diagram for a better drawing.

Comment: I see. Could you provide a picture of the polytopal complex of the tetrahedron?

Comment: Also, please have a look at this picture: https://imgur.com/XJL6H2z. I assume the reason it is not a shelling is that, when the last piece with no number is added to the previous ones, the intersection is an edge and a point, which are not both 1-dim segments of a boundary complex?

Comment: The "polytopal complex of a tetrahedron" is just the tetrahedron. And yes, your stated reason disqualifies the shown ordering from being a shelling in the linked image.